# PHP: referencing a resource in library scope

Tags: php, html, image, uri

I'm writing a little PHP library (a bunch of PHP classes).
One of the classes creates HTML tables where boolean values are represented by icons, i.e. a part of its output might look like this:

```
...<td class="img"><img width="16" height="16" alt="true" src="???/valid_16.png"></td>...
```

The problem is: I don't know how to specify the src attribute.

Of course I know the relative path from the PHP class to the image file (within the library).
But the src attribute requires a URI and I don't want to make assumptions about the eventual location of the library on the server.

So, is it possible to reference the image file such that it's invariant with respect to the actual library location?
Or should I reconsider my design?

Answer (score 0):

You can always make it a requirement for your library users to give the url path of the asset directory as a parameterm so you can use it to prefix your src attributes.

If you are sure that your library's job to generate the html output for the users in this specific case i would make these images a `background-image`, since in css, relative `url()`s are resolved relative to the file's path so if the user's of your library just extract the assets with the css files it will work "out of the box" (given that they add the css file to their site). This will come handy if you later decide to convert these icons to an icon-font (like [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)) to support high DPI displays or scaling.

Comment: Thank you for these valuable suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Based on complex857's suggestions I came up with this solution:

I created a class in the library's main directory that sets up autoloading for the library namespace. 
It also determines the library location (assuming that the library and the code that uses it live under the same document root). 
This class is the only one that the library user must include explicitely. 
It looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace vendor\lib;

class Includer
{
    public static $libUrl;
    public static $libPath;

    public static function getUrl($dir)
    {
        $url = substr($dir, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])); // remove root prefix from dir
        return str_replace('\\', '/', $url) . '/'; // windows...
    }

    public static function registerNamespaceAutoload($namespace, $path)
    {
        // some code to register autoload for given namespace using given path
    }
}

// determine library location
Includer::$libUrl = Includer::getUrl(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))); // lib's top level dir (two levels up relative to vendor\lib\Includer)
Includer::$libPath = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . Includer::$libUrl);

// register autoload for library
Includer::registerNamespaceAutoload('vendor\\lib\\', Includer::$libPath);

?>
```

Usage to get URL for an image located in vendor/lib/images/:

```
<?php

namespace vendor\lib\images;
use vendor\lib\Includer;

class Image
{
    public static function getUrl($fileName)
    {
        return Includer::$libUrl . 'vendor/lib/images/' . $fileName;
    }
}

?>
```

Drawback: This doesn't work when using aliases (in development environments).